# My wireless network does not connect

Tags: wireless, networking

I have just started using Ubuntu, and have always been using windows, so I am a bit of a newbee here.

I installed the 12.04 Precise Pangoline version the other day, and everything seem to work fine, except for the fact that the wireless network doesn't seem to work.

When I go to `System Settings` --> `Network` --> `Wireless` I can't move the bottom to "On". And when I turn Airplane mode off, it automatically sets it back to on when I leave the menu.

I have Windows 7 running on another partition and here I can access the wireless network without any problems.

I am using a Dell Vostro 3450.

Comment: Try the solutions mentioned in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.