# My wireless is hard-blocked

Tags: wireless, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WI-FI doesn't work (Hard Blocked)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked)

I'm new to linux and i am having trouble getting my wireless to work

I've found the following things

```
 Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

and :

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 6c:62:6d:19:38:b9
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.2.0-25-generic-pae firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:fdfe0000-fdfefff
```

Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: Turn on the hardware switch for your wifi adapter.

Comment: What model is your laptop, as robinj says, hard block refers to a real life hardware switch. If you can tell me the model I can look it up.

Comment: MSI CR630 - this is it

Comment: No hardware switch on my laptop, and hardblocked.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

..or what RobinJ mentioned, try the hardware switch on your laptop:

[image: hardware wifi wireless switch]

Comment: robinJ thanks but i believe that if i were able to give you that much info from the terminal than i am able to find which are the keys for turning on my wlan. Unfortunately already tried it and it doesn't work. It doesn't look like the one in the picture provided by medigeek but i have FN+F10. (It didn't work but FN+-> works in controlling the audio level)

Comment: And i tried with rfkill unblock all   ---->    no succes

Comment: This command doesn't work for me. Still have hardblock.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem with the wireless  network my laptop msi cr630 has as a hard unblocker the Fn + F8 . Problem solved sorry to bother you :D

Comment: You could mention your laptop brand and model, so that other users could benefit from this answer as well.

Comment: sorry new to this kind of things      MSI CR630

Comment: No hard swicth on mine, and hard blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it worked for me.

This is how to get the wireless hardswitch to turn on using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Then enter this command to turn it on:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep '8180|acx|at76|ath|b43|bcm|CX|eth|ipw|irmware|isl| lbtf|orinoco|ndiswrapper|NPE|p54|prism|rtl|rt2|rt3 |rt6|rt7|witch|wl'
```

Reboot and see if it stays on.

Comment: This saved my Compaq Presario - one-bizillion upvotes