# inactive enable Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, networking, dhcp

I did some changes on my wi-fi connection to give ip manual and somethings else I do not remember what exactly i did and now Wi-Fi connection is not enable on the menu bar I set my connection again to DHCP but also I do not have any wireless access point. In that bar beside the time on the above there is **Enable Wi-Fi **which is inactive

Update:I did jgrocha's steps. after that I saw

```
.

.

phy0: wireless LAN

Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: yes

.
.
```

I follow [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155391/my-wireless-is-hard-blocked) and my problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

on the command line to see which devices are enabled or disabled.
To enable the device, you can try something like

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

or

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Afterwards, the enable wifi option should be enabled on the applet.