# Can't access wireless on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking

I am new to Ubuntu and have the 13.10 on a **Dell inspiron 2200**.

I can't access the wireless capability at all. I don't see its icon. I know there's an adaptor because it worked on Windows XP. When I run `sudo lshw -C network` I get the following:

```
  *-network:0             
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:02:03.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: driver=wl latency=64
       resources: irq:19 memory:dfdfe000-dfdfffff


  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 8
       bus info: pci@0000:02:08.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:12:3f:1d:ad:66
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.101 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:20 memory:dfdfd000-dfdfdfff ioport:df40(size=64)
```

So I know there's a wireless controller there, but it's just not working. I tried installing drivers on the software updates section but there was nothing there.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 13.01 ? There is no version of Ubuntu called 13.01. Its either 13.04, 13.10, 14.04, or 14.10.

Comment: look at my question may be help yohttp://askubuntu.com/questions/461362/inactive-enable-wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

press CTRL + ALT + T to open a terminal window and type the following to run the network manager:

```
nm-applet &
```