# wifi hotspot is not working..[ hard blocked:yes]

Tags: wireless, 14.04, hp, hot-spot

I'm completely new to Ubuntu , I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed.
I am unable to turn on the wireless key in the network panel.

Whenever I try `rfkill unblock all` and `rfkill list all`
then it shows ->

```
soft blocked : no
hard blocked : yes
```

even if I try to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd>(wireless key in my laptop) the soft block changes but noting happens to the hard blocked!

I use a hp-envy ultrabook model : 1104tx .
Please help me out here , I have tried every possible solution that I am aware of.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WI-FI doesn't work (Hard Blocked)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this HP  model, but on my laptop there is (FN F12) and also another switch button on the side to cut all radio emitter (bluetooth and wireless). It turn on and off the hard block.
hope this help

Answer (score 1):

"Hard Blocked" refers to a hardware issue and "Soft Blocked" indicates the connection is blocked by software (rfkill for example). In other words, rfkill commands have no affect on a hard blocked device.

Check for a physical switch or possibly an fn key that can toggle the wireless on and off. Make sure wireless is enabled in BIOS. If you have a BIOS option for wireless and it's on, turn it off and back on again to see if that fixes the issue.

Alot of people say they have fixed this problem simply by booting into windows, turning wireless on and rebooting back into Ubuntu and they no longer have the problem. Try booting into a Live disk or another linux distro you may have on another partition to see if you can fix the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the additional wireless drivers? I have had the same problem, and if you haven't got your wireless drivers you would need to install them and then (if not already) turn on your wireless card. After that, you may need to restart your computer, if that doesn't work then try typing the command:

```
rfkill list all
```

And if it shows that 'hard blocked' is yes then type:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

If the output is **soft blocked: yes** and **hard blocked: no** then you're good to go!!

Hope this helped,
Paul

Comment: rfkill don't ususally work for hard block, mostly only soft

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect with the router? here is wonderful guide to resolve your issue
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Connections

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.