# Ubuntu 16.04 wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless

I am trying to set up wireless with my newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop.

```
 ifconfig -a
ens5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:b3:42:05:5c  
          inet addr:10.2.102.195  Bcast:10.2.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:12f0:784:df66:35a5:5e8b:1dc4:3539/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::9056:fc9a:b94:6345/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:12f0:784:df66:755f:d4c1:3e0:cb66/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:12f0:784:df66::d8f/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:402616 errors:0 dropped:76 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:209969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:335161688 (335.1 MB)  TX bytes:34790938 (34.7 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:80137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:7796613 (7.7 MB)  TX bytes:7796613 (7.7 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:b2:16:48  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17
```

But

```
nmcli d wifi list
*  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

My interface

```
ls /sys/class/net
ens5  lo  wlp3s0

cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

ens5      no wireless extensions.
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

All friends in lab use wireless connection without any problem.What should I try?

Comment: What does your `/etc/network/interfaces` contain?

Comment: @AlcuinArundel Take a look at my edit!

Comment: That looks OK. What's the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: One last thing: `rfkill list all`

Comment: It looks like you have a Broadcom wireless card, which is notoriously problematic with Ubuntu. Have a look through this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked