3 modules of my laptop are hard blocked what do i do to unblock them?
Dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: yes

Dell-bluetooth: bluetooth
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: yes

Dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
           Soft blocked: no
           Hard blocked: yes

If anyone could help i would be thankful

Maybe the laptop is in "flight" mode, which blocks all radio emitting components? If it's hard blocked, I would imagine it happened via hardware. A good candidate for that would be a key on the physical keyboard, with the Fn + some other function key combo. The icon is some antenna tower on the corresponding function key, on Dell laptops, marked in blue color. You could try that first. If that does not change anything, I would also look into the BIOS. These are all just guesses.

Ah, it's perhaps this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked

If it is just the Dell listings that are hard blocked you may want to echo "blacklist dell-wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/dell-wmi.conf and reboot
